# Cannot read the array length because "this.weeklyHours" is null

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error for my `calculateTotalPay` method and `calculateAveragePay` method. The error message states that it cannot read the array length because `this.weeklyHours` is `null`.

```java
public double calculateAveragePay() {
  double averagePay = 0;
  double totalPay = 0;
 // totalPay = calculateTotalPay();

  averagePay = totalPay / weeklyHours.length;
  return averagePay;
}

public double calculateTotalPay() {
  int totalAmount = 0;
 // for (int index = 0; index < weeklyHours.length; index++)
    totalAmount += weeklyHours[index];
  return totalAmount;
}
```

```
public class Employee {
    private static final int DEFAULT_WEEKS = 52;
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    private double[] weeklyHours;
    //private int numWeeks;

    public Employee(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        double[] weeklyHours = new double[DEFAULT_WEEKS];
    }

    public Employee(String name, double salary, int numWeeks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        double[] weeklyHours = new double[numWeeks];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the *Employee* class constructor methods, you're initializing a *local variable*, as opposed to assigning the *class variable*.

```java
double[] weeklyHours = new double[DEFAULT_WEEKS];
```

```java
double[] weeklyHours = new double[numWeeks];
```

Just remove the declaration type, to access the *class variable*.

```java
weeklyHours = new double[DEFAULT_WEEKS];
```

```java
weeklyHours = new double[numWeeks];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the same bug in both constructors. You are ***shadowing*** the field with a new local variable. Use `this` like you did with the other fields to avoid this class of error.

```
public Employee(String name, double salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    // double[] weeklyHours = new double[DEFAULT_WEEKS];
    this.weeklyHours = new double[DEFAULT_WEEKS];
}

public Employee(String name, double salary, int numWeeks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    // double[] weeklyHours = new double[numWeeks];
    this.weeklyHours = new double[numWeeks];
}
```

You could replace the first constructor with

```
public Employee(String name, double salary) {
    this(name, salary, DEFAULT_WEEKS);
}
```